# Status bar on bottom of window that looks like interface builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

In interface builder and finder, there are windows with a status bar on the bottom of the window that has a neat greyscale effect. What is the correct/proper way to achieve this affect?

Is it a built in interface element or is it done by embedding an image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a [content border](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/setContentBorderThickness:forEdge:).

Comment: While technically this is the answer it still took me a few hours to work out how the heck to do this. Turns out the easiest thing to do is grep the apple source code for these words and theres an example (: Thanks!

Comment: The easiest thing to do used to be to click that link, but Apple changed the URLs and broke it. I've updated it to the new URL that takes you directly to the method.